# using jquery how can i test if parent is first child?

Tags: jquery, parent, children, css-selectors

we have

```
<div class="grandparent">
    <div class="parent"><a href="#">a</a></div>
    <div class="parent"><a href="#">b</a></div>
    <div class="parent"><a href="#">c</a></div>
</div>
```

on hover over any link i want to test if 'parent' is first-child of 'grandparent'
if not i want to apply a class

this is just a simplified example i don't have class names in the element parent and grandparent

Comment: thanks to everyone who responded

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$(document).on('mouseenter','a',function(){
    if($(this).parent().is(':first-child')){
        alert('my parent is first child');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('myParentIsNot');
    }
});
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/9vW84/2/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.grandparent > div').hover(function() {
    // If the child is NOT the first
    if (!$(this).is('div:first-child')) {
        $(this).addClass('not-first');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g2A6C/1/

Note: You will have to adjust this solution to suit your specific DOM elements since you aren't using classnames.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to set styles you can do this with CSS and the adjacent sibling selector (CSS3)

```
.grandparent .parent:first-child ~ .parent:hover a {
    color: red;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/gZDLy/1/)

Comment: I like this, very clean

Comment: @dego89 - Thanks, it doesn't really do what the OP is asking for, adding a class, but usually you add a class for styling, and this seemed like something that could be done with CSS only.

Comment: thanks yours is a great example on how to do that with css but not what i asked

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's .index() to test where it falls below grandparent.

```
  $("div.grandparent").on("mouseenter", "div.parent", function(e) {
    if($(this).parent(".grandparent").children("div.parent").index(this) > 0) {
      $(this).addClass("not-the-first");
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Compare the elements with:

```
$('div > a').mouseover(function () {
    if ($(this).parent()[0] !== $('div > div:first')[0]) $(this).addClass('special')
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/62vZw/)**

Or:

```
$('div > a').mouseover(function () {
    if (!$(this).parent().is($('div > div:first'))) $(this).addClass('special')
})
```

Comment: Binding mouseovers on every 'a' element is overkill. Also, OP wants to add a class to elements that are NOT the first child.

Comment: @aowie1 - relax it was just an example. Updated. Please remove your downvote.

Comment: Removed. It was just to get your attention to provide a better example to OP so you have a fighting chance ;)

Comment: @aowie1 - appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
(function(){

    $("div.grandparent div.parent:not(:first-child)").on('mouseover', function(){
        $(this).addClass("classHere");
        console.log($(this));
    });

})();
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/atgC6/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .not and the :first-child of jquery..
http://jsfiddle.net/7wLtY/

```
$('.parent').not(':first-child').hover(function() {
    $( this ).addClass( "not-first-child" );
  }, function() {
    $( this ).removeClass( "not-first-child" );
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Would probably do it like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/x858q/1/

```
var $parents = $(".parent"); // cache parents

$("a").hover(function(){
    // mouse enters link
    var $par = $(this).parent();

    if($parents.index($par) !== 0){
        $(this).addClass("not-first");
    }
}, function(){
    // mouse leaves link
    $(this).removeClass("not-first");
});
```